# How to find radius of hemisphere in applied problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the stem of a mushroom is modeled as a right circular cylinder with diameter $1$, height $2$, its cap modeled as a hemisphere of radius $a$ the mushroom has axial symmetry, is of uniform density,and its center of mass lies at center of plane where the cap and stem join, then find $a$.

I really need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the mass density is $\rho$.

Then the mass of the stem $m_s$ will be $\rho V_s$, where $V_s$ is the volume of the stem.  Likewise for the cap, $m_c = \rho V_c.$

So, $m_s = \rho \pi r_s^2 h = 2 \pi \rho$ and $m_c = (2/3) \rho \pi r^3 = (2/3) \rho \pi a^3.$

If we take the plane joining them to be $z=0$, positive up, then the center of mass of the stem is $d_s \cdot m_s = 2 \pi \cdot -1 = -2 \pi \rho$, where $d_s$ is the displacement of the center of mass from the plane.

This means that $d_c \cdot m_c = + 2 \pi \rho$.  The center of mass of a hemispherical solid of radius $a$ [lies 3/8ths of the way up from the base](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/495614/7163).  Hence,

$$\frac{3a}{8} \cdot \frac{2 \pi a^3 \rho }{3} = 2 \pi \rho \to a = \sqrt[4]{8} \approx 1.682.$$

Comment: Thank you for the correct solution, I was mistaken. Just one thing: Your link seem to lead to some users profile, I'm guessing it was supposed to lead to some site containing a formula for the "3/8ths"-thing?

Comment: Hah, I copied the wrong link.  Fixed!  (And it was someone else's work, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks, so I don't need to use triple integrals and such?

Comment: I suppose I did "look up some results" rather than solving from first principles.  If you run across a shape for which you don't know where the CM is, then yes, you'll need to integrate over the shape.  The CM of the cylinder shouldn't be too surprising, but I would have needed to calculate the CM of the half-ball had I not found what it was.  (The linked post calculates it.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake though. You used the radius of the cylinder as being equal to 1, when in fact it is 1/2. That results in the answer being 2^(1/4)